# keytool error - NoSuchAlgorithmException - SHA256withRSA

Tags: java, certificate, keytool

I am using Java version - 1.5.0_10
I use keytool to add client certificates to my server trust store. While adding one of those certificates I am getting the below error.

keytool error - NoSuchAlgorithmException - SHA256withRSA

- Is there are a work around for this issue?
- Do I have to upgrade my java?
- Can I point my keytool to a jar and get away with it? If so, how do I do that.

Please help.

Thanks
Kamal

Comment: Java 1.5? Wow, that's certainly antique software.

Comment: Ah!! Thank you. Now, do you have a solution you can suggest or only passing comments? :)

Comment: You could upgrade Java to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Upgrading Java will fix the problem.  A modern version of keytool will support SHA256.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses. The Upgrade has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

SHA256withRSA is implemented by SunRsaSign provider in later updates of Java 1.5

I tested it with java 1.5 update 22.

Here is a piece of code displaying JCA providers and algorithms they implement

```
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class TestSslProviders {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
      Provider p[] = Security.getProviders();
      for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
          System.out.println(p[i]);
          for (Enumeration e = p[i].keys(); e.hasMoreElements();)
              System.out.println("\t" + e.nextElement());
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```